# What does it mean when a job offer description or title are being changed?

Tags: support, jobs

I have applied for a job through [Careers Stack Overflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). Occasionally the same job offer changes description and title. How should I consider this? Did they find a person for this vacancy and they are looking for another with different responsibilities?

If a position is closed, is the applicant informed about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "same job offer changes position and title" I assume that means that company is posting for a new position. If they repost the exact same position again, most likely it means they didn't find an applicant that for their requirements.

Now, as far as notifying candidates if a position has been closed, currently they aren't. I agree though that would be an awesome feature for us to implement. I've been there and I hate when I'm not given the courtesy of knowing I won't be considered for the position. I'm gonna bring this up with the devs and maybe we can implement the feature in the future.

Comment: How can you see anything? The hat is all over your eyes! :-D

Comment: It's ....... difficult.

Comment: Well, it's obvious... you need more hats! :)